# Quickly searching by generated value?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing

I need to make a value generated from multiple fields, then search by that new value.

```
SELECT *
FROM (select 0 a, 1 b) t
where (CASE
WHEN a THEN "First"
WHEN b THEN "Second"
ELSE "Other" END) = "second";
```

It's very slow since indexes can't work. How can i get this type of search to be quick?

My idea is to generate different optimized queries, based on what the value of my search is, before it gets to mysql. But i don't want to do this because my real queries are very complicated so it's a lot of work.

Comment: It's totally not clear what you're asking. The only query you show does not reference any table, so apparently you're trying to optimize one or more queries you haven't shown, against tables you haven't described. All I can say is, "I wish you the best of luck."

Comment: @BillKarwin You can see i'm searching by a case expression. i think that's all that's relevant. it's slow, is there a fast way to do it?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t WHERE b = 1` is indexable and gives an equivalent result. This seems obvious, so there must be something about this question that you're not stating.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have to search by `"first", "second", "other"` strings

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar - I'm with Bill.  You have over-simplified the query for the question.  Please provide an example with more meat in it.